# filter not behaving as expected on status ="ACTIVE"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter

The below code should show the list of users according to selected status,
**JSP code**

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Aggregate</th>
        <th>User id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody >

        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.agId" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.id" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.firstName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.lastName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.mobileNo" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.emailId" /></td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="search.status">
                    <option value=""> Select </option>
                    <option value="ACTIVE"> Active </option>
                    <option value="INACTIVE"> In Active </option>
                    <option value="B"> Blocked </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr ng-repeat="userone in filtereddata = (users.data | filter:search)">
            <td>{{ userone.agId }}</td>
            <td>{{ userone.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ userone.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ userone.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ userone.mobileNo }}</td>
            <td>{{ userone.emailId }}</td>
            <td class="text-center" ng-switch on="userone.status">
                <span class="inac label label-success" ng-switch-when="ACTIVE">Active</span> 
                <span class="inac label label-danger" ng-switch-when="INACTIVE">In Active</span> 
                <span class="inac label label-danger" ng-switch-when="B">Blocked</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller JS code**

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.users.data, newVal);

            console.log($scope.filtered);

            $scope.bigTotalItems = (typeof $scope.filtered == 'undefined' ) ? 0 : $scope.filtered.length;
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.bigTotalItems/$scope.entryLimit);
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
        }, true);
```

It's working fine for INACTIVE and blocked(i.e B) users however **when selected
ACTIVE its showing all users of ACTIVE and  INACTIVE status**

I have given a simple `console.log($scope.filtered)` in Controller js code 
it's actually returning both ACTIVE and INACTIVE members inside the filtered data when selected Active. Its working fine for other selection.

How should I solve this?

Let me know if any additional data is needed

Comment: This question was tagged with `java` tag by mistake. I've removed this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: 'apple',
    status: 'inactive'
  }, {
    name: 'banana',
    status: 'active'
  }, {
    name: 'grape',
    status: 'deleted'
  }, {
    name: 'orange',
    status: 'inactive'
  }, {
    name: 'pear',
    status: 'deleted'
  }, {
    name: 'watermelon',
    status: 'active'
  }]
  
  $scope.filter = function(actual, expected) {
    if (expected == '') return true;
    
    return angular.equals(actual, expected);
  }
  
  $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal) {
    $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.data, newVal, $scope.filter);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  Search:
  <select ng-model="search">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
    <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search:filter">
    {{item.name}} - {{item.status}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="item in filtered">
    {{item.name}} - {{item.status}}
  </div>
</div>
```

By reading the [API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), it looks like you can enforce strict comparison by passing `true` in the 3rd parameter.

`<tr ng-repeat="userone in filtereddata = (users.data | filter:search:true)">`

If you need correct result in your controller, you need to pass in the 3rd param as well.

`$scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.users.data, newVal, $scope.filter);`

Edit: To fix empty result issue when selecting empty filter, we'll need to use a custom filter function. Updated code.

Comment: the issue is still there even after above change

Comment: in above code snippet select any status and then select the 'Select' status, then the complete list should be shown but it's empty.